# How to handle Net::SFTP::Foreign invalid user or password errors?

Tags: perl, sftp

I am using Net::SFTP::Foreign with IO::Pty.

My Login Command is:

```
Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host=> $server_address,
                        user => $user_id,
                        password => $password)
    or die "Could not Connect To Server $server_address: $!";
```

When I am passing invalid entry for server/user/password, it's not throwing the error message. It's simply hanging on the command line and not giving any output ever after 30+ minutes.

Please help how to handle the errors, if there is any invalid input parameters.

If I am passing all the valid values, its working fine.

Comment: By invalid, do you mean a wrong password? Or does this also happen when you use a `$server_address` that is neither a host name nor an IP address?

Comment: yes. wrong password/ wrong server name/wrong user name. if I pass any wrong values, the job is just hanging for long time and its not finishing at all.

Comment: Enable debugging both in the module and in `ssh` and post here the output: `$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug=-1; my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(more => '-vvv', ...);`

Comment: No luck even after the above update. I tried below.  Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug=-1; $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host=> $server_address, user => $user_id, password => $password, more=>'-vvv'); But the job is still hanging off and not giving any output if I pass a wrong host name. Please help!
    or die "Could not Connect To Server $server_address: $!";

Comment: include the debugging output in the question!!!

Comment: Command I used: Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug=-1; $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(more=>'-vvv', host=> $server_address, user => $user_id, password => $password);  cmd line output -> OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ftp_address: Name or service not known.  With this code, the job is handing off and not returning any status. After adding 'timeout=>30' to the login command, it is failing the job when I pass the incorrect host name.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, using the following option, I am able to handle the issue. 
Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug=-1; 
$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new( host=> $server_address, user => $user_id, password => $password, more=>'-vvv', timeout=>30);

This command will handle the wrong host_name, user_id or password. The job will fail after waiting for the no.of seconds given for timeout, if it is not able to establish a connection.